# Want to hide and show an element using select tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. I can hide but can't show. I want to hide and show an element with `select` tag.

If i choose `option value="something"` `#hide` must be hidden and if I choose `something2` (another option in select tag) `#hide` must be shown.

`div` element must be shown and hidden every time I choose options in select tag.

```
<option value="something"></option>
<option value="something2"></option>

<div id="hide"></div>
```

Comment: we need to see your html & js

Comment: Problems formatting your question? `->` http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. And please post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toggle()` hides and shows an element based on a condition, like what the value of the select is:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('#hide').toggle(this.value=='something');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/B6KMH/)

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy . Follow this :

**HTML:**

```
<select class = 'select'>
<option value="something">1</option>
<option value="something2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="hide"> Help</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.select').on('click', function() {
    $('#hide').toggle(this.value=='something');
});
```

This uses the `toggle` method and finds the class `select` of the selection choice.

Find the working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/7H4EW/